# Using JS namespaces to make an Accordion work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, accordion

I'm having trouble integrating this accordion JS into my project. I have set up namespaced functions in JS, which works fine. The accordion works fine independently, but when I put it within my project it doesn't work properly.

The code current in the namespace works fine, it has no resemblance or reference to anything in the HTML page that requires the 'accordion' to work. I just don't know how to put in the 'accordion' code into the JS and make it work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle-accordion").on("click", function() {
    var accordionId = $(this).attr("accordion-id"),
      numPanelOpen = $(accordionId + ' .collapse.in').length;

    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    if (numPanelOpen == 0) {
      openAllPanels(accordionId);
    } else {
      closeAllPanels(accordionId);
    }
  })

  openAllPanels = function(aId) {
    console.log("setAllPanelOpen");
    $(aId + ' .panel-collapse:not(".in")').collapse('show');
  }
  
  closeAllPanels = function(aId) {
    console.log("setAllPanelclose");
    $(aId + ' .panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
  }
});

//Namespace for current functions
var nameSpace = {
     // ** Products **
Products: function() {
    // ** Products ** - Form input error
    var businessForm = document.getElementById('businesscontactus_form');
    const companyName = document.getElementById('companyName');
    const businessRepName = document.getElementById('businessRepName');
    const companyPosition = document.getElementById('companyPosition');
    const businessEmail = document.getElementById('businessEmail');
    const businessMessage = document.getElementById('businessMessage');

    businessForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        checkInputs();
    });

    function checkInputs() {
        // trim to remove the whitespaces
        const companyNameValue = companyName.value.trim();
        const businessRepNameValue = businessRepName.value.trim();
        const companyPositionValue = companyPosition.value.trim();
        const businessEmailValue = businessEmail.value.trim();
        const businessMessageValue = businessMessage.value.trim();

        if (companyNameValue === '') {
            setErrorFor(companyName, 'Company Name must be entered');
        } else {
            setSuccessFor(companyName);
        };

        if (businessRepNameValue === '') {
            setErrorFor(businessRepName, 'Name cannot be blank');
        } else {
            setSuccessFor(businessRepName);
        };

        if (businessEmailValue === '') {
            setErrorFor(businessEmail, 'Email cannot be blank');
        } else if (!isEmail(businessEmailValue)) {
            setErrorFor(businessEmail, 'Not a valid email');
        } else {
            setSuccessFor(businessEmail);
        };

        if (companyPositionValue === '') {
            setErrorFor(companyPosition, 'Company position cannot be blank');
        } else {
            setSuccessFor(companyPosition);
        };

        if (businessMessageValue === '') {
            setErrorFor(businessMessage, 'Message cannot be blank');
        } else {
            setSuccessFor(businessMessage);
        };
    };

    function setErrorFor(input, message) {
        const formControl = input.parentElement;
        const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
        formControl.className = 'business-form-control error';
        small.innerText = message;
    };

    function setSuccessFor(input) {
        const formControl = input.parentElement;
        formControl.className = 'business-form-control success';
    };

    function isEmail(businessEmail) {
        return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(businessEmail);
    };
},
Staff: function() {
    // ** STAFF ** 
    const customer_contactus_form = document.getElementById('customercontactus_form');
    const customerCUName = document.getElementById('customerCUName');
    const customerCUSubject = document.getElementById('customerCUSubject');
    const customerCUEmail = document.getElementById('customerCUEmail');
    const customerCUMessage = document.getElementById("customerCUMessage");
    const customerCUDisclaimerBox = document.getElementById('customerCUDisclaimerBox');

    customer_contactus_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        checkcustomerCU_Inputs();
    });

    function checkcustomerCU_Inputs() {
        //trim to remove the whitespaces
        const customerCUNameValue = customerCUName.value.trim();
        const customerCUSubjectValue = customerCUSubject.value.trim();
        const customerCUEmailValue = customerCUEmail.value.trim();
        const customerCUMessageValue = customerCUMessage.value.trim();

        if (customerCUNameValue === '') {
            setErrorForCU(customerCUName, 'Please enter your name');
        } else {
            setSuccessForCU(customerCUName);
        };

        if (customerCUSubjectValue === '') {
            setErrorForCU(customerCUSubject, 'Please enter a subject in order for us to help you better.');
        } else {
            setSuccessForCU(customerCUSubject);
        };

        if (customerCUEmailValue === '') {
            setErrorForCU(customerCUEmail, 'Email cannot be blank');
        } else if (!isEmail(customerCUEmailValue)) {
            setErrorForCU(customerCUEmail, 'Not a valid email');
        } else {
            setSuccessForCU(customerCUEmail);
        };

        if (customerCUMessageValue === '') {
            setErrorForCU(customerCUMessage, 'Please enter a message.');
        } else {
            setSuccessForCU(customerCUMessage);
        };

        if (!customerCUDisclaimerBox.checked) {
            setErrorForCU(customerCUDisclaimerBox, 'Please check box and accept terms and conditions.');
        } else {
            setSuccessForCU(customerCUDisclaimerBox);
        };
};
```

```css
// Accordion CSS
body {
  color: #6a6c6f;
  background-color: #f1f3f6;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #e4e5e7;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  float: right;
  transition: transform .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s linear;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\2212";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
  content: "\002b";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.accordion-option {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.accordion-option .title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.accordion-option .toggle-accordion {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #6a6c6f;
}

.accordion-option .toggle-accordion:before {
  content: "Expand All";
}

.accordion-option .toggle-accordion.active:before {
  content: "Collapse All";
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="accordion-option">
    <h3 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle-accordion active" accordion-id="#accordion"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show the namespaced code which didn't work so that we can help you debug it. From the code you've provided it's not clear how you plan to provide the Element references to instantiate the accordions on, when using your `nameSpace` object.

Comment: The code in the namespace (currently) works fine. What I can't do or figure out is to add the new accordion code code I have created to a) Go inside the namespace, b) be able to work with the HTML page (just the snippet provided). I have edited the original question to hopefully make this more clear -let me know if it's not, thanks!

Comment: To make it work, you can simply just copy the entirety of your existing document.ready handler in to the `nameSpace.Accordion()` function body, and then call that function from doc.ready.

Comment: Ok, and then where do I put the 'onclick="nameSpace.Accordion()"' within my HTML? The accordion code references several independent items in the HTML code provided above, such as '.toggle-accordion' -will this cause a conflict if I place the code in my namespace?

Comment: `where do I put the 'onclick="nameSpace.Accordion()"' within my HTML?` Nowhere. JS should never be mixed with HTML. Put it in a click event handler within document.ready

Comment: `The accordion code references several independent items in the HTML code provided above, such as '.toggle-accordion' -will this cause a conflict if I place the code in my namespace?` Possibly, this is why I originally asked to see your attempt to understand more about the context you're expecting to use the code within.

Comment: I've thrown up all the code I have in the JS file. All I'm trying to do is add the accordion feature to the namespace and then for it to work in the HTML file when the user clicks on 'Expand all' or clicks to expand individual chooses points.